# Can I create one jar file that contain my jar project and javadoc?

Tags: java

I'm developping an asset.
When I want to give it to a third party user, I'm usually doing 2 exports : jar file and & javadoc folder. 
The third party user, import the jar file into his project and attach my generated javadoc to the jar file. (and then the thid party user can see the documentation when he use my methods)

Is there a way to export one file (jar + javadoc) such that the third party user will import just one file. (and when the third party use the classes and methods from my jar, he will see the comments (javdoc) I added ?

Thanks